# Is my car worth driving again? What options do I have?

Tags: car, stall

I had an accident more than 15months ago. The damage was that I hit a pot hole and the car caught fire around the engine and suddenly stopped, couldn't be restarted. I followed the procedures and made insurance claims. To date, I have not been assisted by the insurance. The car remains stalled at the insurance car yard and has been there for the 15months.
Ots a Mercedes A170 model made in 2005.
Now since it has not been driven since then, what are the options for me?
Do I claim more for damages that come with not being used for such a long time?
Do I sue the insurance company for damages and demand compensation for not being helped and destroying the car?
I followed due processes and reported then to the insurance regulatory authority but it seems they go to bed with them.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's entirely insurer dependent. Nothing to do with maintenance or repair. Sorry - you just need to keep chasing insurers - they don't want to have to pay out.

Comment: The insurance company has not provided you a rental? Seek legal advise from an **attorney**.

Comment: Thanks guys for advice. I got an attorney this morning. We'll be looking at ll the options on the table. It's amazing that even after asking for a rental car, they just ignored it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had an engine compartment fire in my own car.  To make an informed decision, have a mechanic take a careful inventory of the damage even if you must pay out-of-pocket for the estimate.  It's likely the necessary repairs will be relatively straightforward and inexpensive, but you must know for sure beforehand.  As an owner of several Mercedes over two decades, I would strongly urge you to take the car to a small, independent mechanic rather than a dealership or shinny facility.

With an assessment in hand, you will be in a much better negotiating position with your insurance company.  If you wait for insurance to make the first move, you could be waiting forever.  From the insurer's perspective, your continued threats will only raise the potential for big expenses, and they will continue to stall.

In my case, I was able to extinguish the brief, but intense, petroleum fire quickly and so there was only minor damage.  It looked ugly and smelly at first, but I was amazed at how many parts -- hoses, plastic sensors, wires, etc. -- have a good deal of flame resistance and work just fine after being partially melted.  If you are as lucky as I was, you may find it's not worth making an insurance claim at all.